# How would I find the equation of a graph using matrices?

Tags: matrices

Assuming the graph below is a 5th degree polynomial, how would I go about finding its equation using matrices? 
[image]
Edit:
So if I had the data points:

$A(2006, 531.37), B(2013, 484.13), C(2028, 543.71), D(2062, 53.06), E(2076, 91.88), F(2086, 11.94)$

what would the matrices look like?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Well by plugging in six points you should get six equations in the coefficients that you can solve using matrices.

Comment: Edited to provide more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach for a polynomial of degree $n$ is to find $n+1$ equations of the form
$$y_i = f(x_i) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \cdot (x_i)^k$$
and solve the corresponding linear equation system to obtain a solution $(a_0,a_1,\ldots, a_n)$ which defines the polynomial. Of course you can write the LES in matrix form, i.e.

$$\pmatrix{1 & x_0 & \ldots & x_0^n \\ 1 & x_1 & \ldots & x_1^n\\ \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\ 1 & x_n & \ldots & x_n^n} \cdot \pmatrix{a_0 \\ \vdots \\ a_n} = \pmatrix{y_0 \\ y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_n}.$$

**Edit:** With your data points, the matrices would be

$$\pmatrix{1 & 2006 & 2006^2 & \ldots & 2006^5 \\ 
1 & 2013 & 2013^2 & \ldots & 2013^5 \\
1 & 2028 & 2028^2 & \ldots & 2028^5 \\
1 & 2062 & 2062^2 & \ldots & 2062^5 \\
1 & 2076 & 2076^2 & \ldots & 2076^5 \\
1 & 2086 & 2086^2 & \ldots & 2086^5 } \cdot \pmatrix{a_0 \\ \vdots \\ a_n} = \pmatrix{531.37 \\ 
484.13\\ 
543.71\\
53.06\\
91.88\\
11.94}$$

Comment: Using the data points provided, what would this look like?

Comment: @IsaacBeeman I edited my answer to give you a clear idea what you have to compute.

Comment: So if $a_0,a_1, \ldots$ are used to find the equation in the form $y=a_5x^5+a_4x^4\ldots$, how do I find what $a_0, a_1, \ldots$ are?

Comment: $a_0,\ldots, a_n$ are the variables of your equations. You solve the linear equation system to obtain $a_0,\ldots, a_n$. After doing this, you know that the polynomial you were looking for is $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots + a_5 x^5$

Comment: By LES, do you mean that $531.37=a_0+2006^1a_1+ \ldots +2006^5a_5$?

Comment: @IsaacBeeman Yes, LES = linear equation system. The equality of the vectors on both sides of the matrix equation induces $n$ linear equations.